# Need to subtract two times for difference. Not getting results I need

Tags: php, string, time

I have tried exploding the times, to work with parts before and after the ":" with minimal success. I am receiving both times via XML feed, so I can convert my received strings as necessary, or multiply them by another figure to work with as I need.

```
$time_1 = "00:59.8408";

$time_2 = "01:00.4734";

$difference = $time_2 - $time_1;
```

or another way of calculating the difference, should give me back

```
0.6326
```

I will be happy to accept any advice. I have attempted subtracting strtotime converted variables, I have as I mentioned above exploded the string with unfavorable results. The, what I believe is, milliseconds have also been an obstacle that I have not worked with in the past.

I appreciate you reading this.

Comment: How are you exploding it , paste the code here and also mention the error you are facing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus operator in PHP only works with numbers. Your strings will be converted to numbers which then is 1 - 0, so the difference is 1:

```
$time_1 = "00:59.8408";

$time_2 = "01:00.4734";

$difference = $time_2 - $time_1;

var_dump($difference); # int(1)
```

Instead write a function that converts the string into seconds as a float like in this example:

```
/**
 * convert time string to seconds
 *
 * @param string $time %i:%s.%u
 * @return float
 */
function time_to_seconds($time) {
    sscanf($time, '%d:%f', $minutes, $seconds);
    return $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}
```

This is pretty straight forward: scan the string first for digits, then the colon and then a float. As the first digits are the minutes, multiply those with 60 and add the seconds as float (one minute is 60 seconds). Return the result (no error checking in there, see [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf) to turn this into production code.

Then do the operation with the results:

```
$difference_in_seconds = time_to_seconds($time_2) - time_to_seconds($time_1);

var_dump($difference_in_seconds); # double(0.6326)
```

And that's it. The most important part is that you need to know how to treat the data that is *encoded* in your string(s) here. Parse the string according to that.

Comment: That absolutely was a great solution. Much appreciated. I also added in number_format($difference_in_seconds, 4) after for the right precision I needed. +1